# Why react query cache empty after reloading page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, next.js, react-query

im new with nextjs and react query, im really appreciate for any answer, and sorry for my bad english..
So im using nextjs v.12 and react query v3, and using react query devtools. I have a page where im using useInfiniteQuery to fetch data and populate it like a blogpost. after login im direct the to the page and its work well i got the data on the page and on the devtools too. but after i reload the page, the data on the page still good but the devtools becomes empty. The problem is, when the memory on devtools empty, all the function like fetchOnFocus doesnt work anymore and i cant mutate the data if i post a new blogpost. How to use react query in a good and best practice ? thank you before

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just found whats wrong with my code, so i missed the hydrate on my root component thats why.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).